# How to implement mongoose-auto-increment in this fullstack?

Tags: mongoose, angular-fullstack

Can you please help any how to integrate mongoose-auto-increment in this fullstack?

Comment: A auto increment after or before which command ? What's the purpose ?

Comment: Like Ex. already have a user model. So user_id i want increment like 1,2,3....

Comment: [MongoDB - Auto-Increment Sequence](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm) Maybe this tutorial can help you